# Identity on Laplace transform of a random variable and PMF

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative discrete random variable with PMF equal to $p_X(x)=P(X=0)$ and $$M_X=\sum_X e^{xs} p_X(x)$$ the transform of $X$.

I can not figure out why the following holds $$p_X(0)=\lim_{s\to -\infty} M_X(s).$$

Couldn't someone be so kind to explain what actually happens here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{s\to -\infty} M_X(s)=\lim_{s\to -\infty}e^{0s}p_X(0)+\lim_{s\to -\infty}\sum_{x \geq 1} e^{xs}p_X(s)$. For $x \geq 1$ note that $e^{xs} \to 0$ as $s \to -\infty$. So only the first term remains and you get the limit as $p_X(0)$.

A rigorous justification for the limit in the second term can be given using DCT.

Comment: Couldn't you elaborate further on the limit in the second term?

Comment: Oh, it seems I actually see how to justify the second term. Since $e^{xs}p_X(x)\leq e^{xs}$ then $\sum_{x\geq 1}e^{xs}p_X(x)\leq \sum_{x\geq 1}e^{xs}=-\frac{e^s}{e^s-1}$ and $\lim_{s\to -\infty}-\frac{e^s}{e^s-1}=0$.